# Multiple URL redirects through a form using PHP

Tags: php, forms

I was hoping to see if I could get some help from yeah on a project I am working on.

I am super lost right now, but what I need to happen is when the user fills in the form if they choose one of the drop-downs and the home radio button is selected as well as them entering a San Diego zip code it takes them to whatever that url is within that drop-down.

If they don't enter a San Diego zip code it takes them to a national page based on the drop-down. That part is actually fully complete and working. The client than turned around and said if they choose the office radio button and one of the selected drop-downs in the list it takes them to an office version page of whatever that drop-down was. Either being water delivery, coffee services or water filtration.

I am totally lost on how I could go about making the url redirect based on the different radio buttons, so they need the home radio button to go to the regular drop-downs and the office when selected to go to a completely different url based on the office option. So it would be office water delivery or office coffee services.

I am super unsure of how to go about making three different url redirections based on one office radio button selection. Anyways I really could use a hand on this thank you. The source code is below. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setAction(nPage){
        document.forms[0].action = nPage;
    }
</script>

<div class="home-form">
    <form method='get' id='gform_1' action='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/form-handler/'>
        <div class="serviceinput"
            <label for="services">Services: </label>
            <select id="selection" name="selection">
                <option value=''>Select a Service</option>
                <option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/'>Water Delivery</option>
                <option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/coffee-delivery/'>Coffee Services</option>
                <option value='http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-filtration-systems/'>Water Filtration</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <div class="zipcode">
            <label for="zip">Zip Code: </label>
            <input name="zip" type="text" maxlength="5" id="zip" /></div>
            <div class="frontradio"><input name="home" type="radio" id="homeradio" />
            <div class="homelabel"> <label for="homeradio">Home</label></div>
            <input name="home" type="radio" id="officeradio" />
            <label for="officeradio">Office</label></div>
            <div class="homebutton">
                <input type='submit' id="submithome" name="did_submit" value="Get Started!">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

FORM HANDLER:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['zip'])){
        $sandiego = array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173', '92562', '92563', '92590', '92591', '92592', '92596');
        if (in_array($_GET['zip'], $sandiego)){
            header("Location: ".$_GET['selection']."?zip=".$_GET['zip']."&type=".$_GET['type']);
        } else {
            header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/");
        }
    }
    exit;
?>
```

SITE WHERE FORM IS ACTUALLY AT:

```
http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? What are the possible choices in the end?

Comment: This div feels cold, give him a complete coat (missing >)... <div class="serviceinput"

Comment: On a sidenote, generally be careful about handling unsanitized input like $_GET['type'] ... I'm not exactly sure what it was supposed to do but whitelisting its values may be an option. Of course, it may also be completely OK in this instance, just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing up your priorities. For one, don't put the target id into those option values. Use plain values like '1', '2', '3' etc.

The 'magic' happens in your evaluation method.
First, evaluate whether home or office is selected.

```
if($_GET["home"] == 1) { //Assumes that selecting 'office' returns you this value.
} else {
}
```

Next, inside that selection, fill arrays with the target data.

```
$urls = array();
if($_GET["home"] == 1) { //Assumes that selecting 'office' returns you this value.
    $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/"
    //rinse and repeat
} else {
    $urls[] = "http://45.22.79.62/~pftech/water-delivery-service/"
    //rinse and repeat
}
```

At this point, you have a valid array, which relates directly to the selected dropdownbox in dependance of the selected radiobutton.

```
$URL = $urls[$_GET["selection"]];
```

Now you just need to pass that URL to your header function and you're good to go.

Just for the sake of completeness, here's the suggested code:

Handler:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['zip'])){
        $sandiego = array('91911', '91914', '91915', '91932', '91942', '91945', '91950', '92014', '92025', '92027', '92029', '92037', '92064', '92065', '92067', '92071', '92075', '92101', '92102', '92103', '92104', '92105', '92106', '92107', '92108', '92109', '92110', '92111', '92113', '92114', '92115', '92116', '92117', '92118', '92119', '92120', '92121', '92122', '92123', '92124', '92126', '92127', '92128', '92129', '92130', '92131', '92132', '92134', '92135', '92139', '92140', '92145', '92147', '92154', '92173', '92562', '92563', '92590', '92591', '92592', '92596');
        if (in_array($_GET['zip'], $sandiego)){
            $urls = array();
            if($_GET["home"] == 1) { //Assumes that selecting 'office' returns you this value.
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office_water-delivery-service/"
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office_coffee-delivery/"
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/office_water-filtration-systems/"
            } else {
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/home_water-delivery-service/"
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/home_coffee-delivery/"
                $urls[] = "http://50.22.79.62/~pftech/home_water-filtration-systems/"
            }
            if($_GET['selection'] < 3 && $_GET['selection'] >= 0) {
                $URL = $urls[$_GET['selection']];
                header("Location: $URL?zip=$_GET[zip]");
            } else header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/"); //Illegal input
        } else {
            header("Location: http://www.pureflo.com/");
        }
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Your HTML for the selection box would look like this:

```
<select id="selection" name="selection">
    <option value='-1'>Select a Service</option>
    <option value="0">Water Delivery</option>
    <option value="1">Coffee Services</option>
    <option value="2">Water Filtration</option>
</select>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am a little lost can you explain more on the radio buttons as far as how they know which drop-down is selected and what code I would actually need to change in my current PHP.  I am not that great at PHP so any kind of examples are awesome.  I just need a little more insight to it and what I would need to add into my current code. Could you just be a little more clear.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @SchellShockDesigns I believe this little 'example' will help you out on your way. Be sure to check the return value of your radio button. When in doubt, add a `value` property to it.

Comment: I am still having issues trying to get to the office page, I pretty much used the exact code above with very small changes, but I only get sent to the home selection urls and none of the office selection urls.  Can someone help me out and tell me what is wrong with the code or what I might change so I can get sent to the office services if the office radio is selected.  Than I get sent to the home services if the home radio button is selected.  I am really lost here on why that wouldn't already work. I figured it would but I only get sent to the home radio selections url. Let meknow if you can

Comment: @SchellShockDesigns First things first, echo the content of `$_GET['home']`. Everythings starts from there.